# Spring Boot \ JWT: The method ok(T) in the type ResponseEntity is not applicable for the arguments (JwtResponse)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this method below.

JwtResponse is a simple POJO.

Why do I get the error in subject on

```
ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse...
```

and how to fix it?

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
    
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();      
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
                                             userDetails.getId(), 
                                             userDetails.getUsername(), 
                                             userDetails.getEmail(), 
                                             roles));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should have been:

```
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
                userDetails.getId(), 
                userDetails.getUsername(), 
                userDetails.getEmail(), 
            roles));
```

Comment: I actually was looking for the reason behind your error, but I found that what you wrote was normal, for eexample if you go into the `ok(T)` method you will find the exact same implementation as `ok().body(T)` which makes it difficult to understand !